# Shortcut to address item in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

In this code branch, I'm trying to rewrite the statement that's commented out (which works) with the shorthand version below. Is it possible? My attempt throws an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

```
if(is_category())
    {
    /*  
        $my_category_ads = get_option('mycategory_fields');
        if($my_category_ads[get_query_var('cat')]['my_cat_ads']) return;
    */
    if(get_option('mycategory_fields')[get_query_var('cat')]['my_cat_ads']) 
    return;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array dereferencing from functions (your shortcut syntax `get_option()[][]`) is currently not supported in PHP (but it's coming in a future version).

Your commented-out code (assigning `get_option()` to a var then indexing it) is the shortest possible way. However, I suggest you indent it properly and break it into lines where appropriate; otherwise it's really hard to read as it is.

Here's how it'd look following [WordPress's coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#PHP) (you don't have to follow it yourself of course):

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $my_category_ads = get_option('mycategory_fields');

    if ( $my_category_ads[get_query_var('cat')]['my_cat_ads'] )
        return;
}
```

Comment: I've always wondered why this isn't allowed though -- would it somehow cause some strange side-effects that they decided to disallow it?

Comment: @casablanca: I've wondered too. Probably just couldn't figure out how to do it the past years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About formatting: I just formatted it on one line so the //comment would make sense. I could have used /* */ and kept the formatting intact as you suggest, I think I'll change it for the archives.

Answer (score 0):

A workable workaround is to return ArrayObject results (with ::ARRAY_AS_PROPS). Those can be accessed with array[] or attribute-> syntax alike. It wouldn't look very charming in your case though:

```
get_option('mycat')->{get_var('cat')}->{'my_cat_sleeps'};
```

Also I would avoid turning the subarrays into objects too unless absolutely necessary.